# How to search both in range and match query in one merged request using Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two assembled queries that work as expected.

First one uses constant score, while matching range between two values:

```
GET /_search
{    
    "query" : {        
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "range" : {
                    "locationId" : {
                        "gte" : 100012138,
                        "lt"  : 101000349
                    }
                }                
            }            
        }        
    }    
}
```

The second one searches for bool.

```
GET /_search
{        
      "query": {         
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "match": {
                            "name": "Barcelona"                         
                        }                        
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
      }
```

}

Now I need to merge them and I am struggling how, because tried many combinations of putting in different scopes, but not successful.

So this query returns an error.

```
GET /_search
{        
      "query": {         
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "match": {
                            "name": "sídlisko"                         
                        }                        
                    }]
                }
            }
        },
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "range" : {
                    "locationId" : {
                        "gte" : 100012138,
                        "lt"  : 1000010349
                    }
                }                
            }            
        }                  
    }                     
}
```

Error:

> ... failed to parse search source. expected field name but got
>   [START_OBJECT]

Answer (score 1):

You could just put constant score query inside bool must clause

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "name": "sidlisko"
              }
            },
            {
              "constant_score": {
                "filter": {
                  "range": {
                    "locationId": {
                      "gte": 100012138,
                      "lt": 1000010349
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this query more optimised than putting bool in query and range within a filter?

Comment: I think your query is perfect, **filters**  are not used for scoring anyways. You could also get rid of must clause as there is only one match query

Comment: But as I checked, I got better scoring using your solution. Why it is that? Now I don't know what query is better. Can you give me one more explanation please?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "better", with constant score inside bool clause it will add to final score but with filter wont affect the score. You could use [explain api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) to see how score is calculated.

Comment: I am Sorry for not being clear. I mean the performance and the logic, so I'd llike to understand, what is better to use: My query is supposed to be used for search within about 5 mil. documents. Actually, I need an exact result and I don't need to take the score into account. I just mentioned the score values, because they are very high using your solution.

Comment: Since scoring is not important, your query is good and also more readable I think. performance will be better with your query, also filters will be [cached](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/filter-caching.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to establish this query and it appears to work.
This looks as the most optimised one.

```
GET /_search
{        
    "query": {         
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "match": {
                            "fullAddress": "sidlisko"                         
                        }                        
                    }]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "range" : {
                    "locationId" : {
                        "gte": 100012138,
                        "lt": 1000010349
                    }
                }                
            } 
        }
    }                    
}
```